# Spark MySQL connector in java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I want to connect spark and MySQL. I tried the following code:

```
public class Get_Data_From_MySQL implements Serializable {

private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Get_Data_From_MySQL.class);

private static final String MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = "root";
private static final String MYSQL_PWD = "";

private static final SparkSession sparkSession =
        SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark2JdbcDs").getOrCreate();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JDBC connection properties
    final Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
    connectionProperties.put("user", MYSQL_USERNAME);
    connectionProperties.put("password", MYSQL_PWD);
    connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    final String dbTable =
            "(select age from employe";
      //Load MySQL query result as Dataset
    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF =
            sparkSession.read()
                    .jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, dbTable, "age", 10001, 499999, 10, connectionProperties);
```

I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: Mauvais 'handshake'
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:659)
```

at this line :

```
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF =sparkSession.read().jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, dbTable, "age", 10001, 499999, 10, connectionProperties);
```

I checked the MySQL user and password, everything is correct.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are facing can means that the DB isn't reachable at all. This problem can occur due to any reason may be IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong, or the hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server, or Port number may be missing, or DB server is down. There can be many reasons, so I would suggest you go through your approach once again and keep a check on everything.
Connect through terminal and check

Comment: I solved it by changing the version of mysql connector . Thank you

Comment: There was actually a syntax error, I was able to solve it by doing some modifications. The database connection was not an issue. Thanks again for the response

Answer (score 0):

```
  package JavaSpark.Javs.SQL;

   import java.util.Properties;

   import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
   import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;


 public class sparkSqlMysql {


private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(sparkSqlMysql.class);

private static final SparkSession sparkSession =
        SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark2JdbcDs").getOrCreate();    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JDBC connection properties
    
    final Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
    connectionProperties.put("user", "root");
    connectionProperties.put("password","mypassword");
    connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     // Load MySQL query result as Dataset
    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF2 =
            sparkSession.read()
                    .jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SQLprep", "customer", connectionProperties);
    
    jdbcDF2.show();
 }
```